# using SSR data in Layout Component on Next.JS

Tags: layout, next.js, darkmode

I am trying to implement dark mode to my project. But I can't understand this logic.
So in my `_app.js` file I have a `Layout` component like below

```
  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-auto flex flex-col transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out">
      <Head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <main className="mt-14 md:mt-20 px-4 md:px-16 py-4 w-full">
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

So here in the `Header` component I have a toggle switch to switch the theme.

Then, in my `index.js` file in the `pages` folder, I have following:

```
   return (
        <Provider data={{products, categories, theme}}>
            <ThemeProvider>
                <AnimatePresence>
                    <Background>
                        <MainContainer/>
                    </Background>
                </AnimatePresence>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
```

This is where I get all the data from the server via `getServerSideProps`.

So in this logic as you can see `Layout` (where the `Header`) is being initialed before I actually get the data from the server.

This causes  some problems.

1.I don't wan't to use `Header` in every single page separetaly, so I can't move it down.

2.If I await the content to be loaded, that gives me a strange visual effect like my dark theme switch starts from a initial default value then when the content is loaded moving to actually place, as well as the background color firstly loading white let's say and then being dark and so on, so that's not a good UX practice.

BTW, I hold selected theme value in the server cookie.
All I wan't to do is, to hold selected theme and use it on reload without actually any visual bug. So the page should be initialized directly with selected theme color

My Question is:

In this case how should be the best practice of a Layout logic?

Thank you!

Comment: _"you can see `Layout` is being initialed before I actually get the data from the server"_ - That's not correct. `getServerSideProps` will run on the server before any React code runs. If the theme logic depends on cookies, why don't you check the cookies in `getServerSideProps` and pass down the props needed for the theme?